# Use MSSQL and MySQL with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I am trying to connect my application to two databases. One is MySQL and one is MSSQL. I tried to find a place to start on Google, but I wasn't successful. I didn't found anything useful on previous questions similar to mine on StackOverflow.

Did any of you connected CI app with MySQL and MSSQL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can put your db config on application/config/database.php like this example:

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;

/*MYSQL DB config EXMPALE */
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DATABASE_NAME';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
//...


/* MSSQL DB config EXMPALE, note the first param my_mssql */

$db['my_mssql']['hostname'] = 'SQL SERVER IP';
$db['my_mssql']['username'] = 'username';
$db['my_mssql']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['my_mssql']['database'] = 'DATABASE_NAME';
$db['my_mssql']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
//...
```

Note that we made the default group is mysql so if you call 
$this->db->..
it's will use the default group db.

for query with another connection ex. MSSQL  you will add something like this in your model

```
class example_model extends CI_Model
{
    var $mssql;
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->mssql = $this->load->database ( 'my_mssql', TRUE );
    }

    function get_some_mssql_rows(){
       //use $this->mssql instead of $this->db
       $query = $this->mssql->query('select * from mssql_table');
       //...
    }

    function get_some_mysql_rows(){
       //use  $this->db for default 
       $query = $this->db->query('select * from mysql_table');
       //...
    }
}
```

you can use this way for many dbs connections like read replica for example

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add both database connection details in the "application/config/database.php" file.  Make sure you set the dbdriver field correctly for each, i.e. "mysql" and "mssql".

Comment: Personally I'd recommend using PDO instead of the mssql and mysql functions

Comment: This is the database connection that's being set up.  You're free to use PDO, mysqli or any other methods you want once you've connected.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the below setup

In database.php file put the below. Note replace the place holders for the hostname, username,password and database for both configs.

```
active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'username' => '<username>',
    'password' => '<password>',
    'database' => '<database>',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['MSSQL'] = array(
    'hostname' => '<MSSQLHOSTIP\INSTANCE>',
    'username' => '<mssqluser>',
    'password' => '<mssqlpassword>',
    'database' => '<mssqldatabasename>',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Second config uses MSSQL as group name and this will be used to load the DB in the model class below.
*I tried the config with less options and it would not load so I used all the options from the default config*

Define a class variable `var $mssql` and initialize in the constructor using `$this->mssql = $this->load->database ( 'MSSQL', TRUE );`

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    var $mssql;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->mssql = $this->load->database ( 'MSSQL', TRUE );
    }

    function GetUsers(){

        $query = $this->mssql->query('Select * from [YOURTABLE]');

        $res = $query->result();

        return $res;    
    }
}
```

The results are returned as an array of objects.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'    => 'sqlsrv:server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=YourDatabaseName',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'YourDatabaseName',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'save_queries' => TRUE);
```