# How can I build a query with query builder in CodeIgniter with mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

My Model function

```
public function getUser($username,$password){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $this->db->from('users_master');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

Error Response : Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_sqlsrv_driver::select()

Using sqlsrv driver with IIS server and CI version 3.1

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515477/use-mssql-and-mysql-with-codeigniter

Comment: If you want to see the SQL being generated use, [get_compiled_select](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get_compiled_select).

Comment: show us your DB connection

Answer (score 0):

I tried with configuration change in database.php

```
$query_builder = TRUE;
```

and tried with clear cache and try.